# replace NA value in a data frame from a list or matrix not in order

Tags: r, replace, tidyr

Hi I have a matrix with 10 values and I would like to replace it in a column of a data frame. I was able to do it with tidyverse and ifelse but the order get all messed up.

```
data <- data.frame("SN" = 1:10, "Age" = c(NA,15,NA,80,45,NA,90,11,NA,NA), "Name" = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"))
newAge <- c(9,5,31,25,65)

data$Age <- ifelse(is.na(data$Age), newAge, data$Age)
```

The order gets all messed up after the code ran. The replacement is not even correct. Please help!

```
SN    Age    Name
1      9      A
2      15     B
3      31     C
4      80     D
5      45     E
6      9      F
7      90     G
8      11     H
9      25     I
10     65     J
```

Comment: `replace(data$Age,is.na(data$Age),newAge)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of `NA` values is same as length of `newAge` you can directly assign them.

```
data$Age[is.na(data$Age)] <- newAge
data

#   SN Age Name
#1   1   9    A
#2   2  15    B
#3   3   5    C
#4   4  80    D
#5   5  45    E
#6   6  31    F
#7   7  90    G
#8   8  11    H
#9   9  25    I
#10 10  65    J
```